# Expected identifier before "{" token + confused by earlier errors, bailing out

Tags: iphone, objective-c, quartz-2d

I am learning game programming on Objective-C and typing code as I follow along this book. I've been able to clean up all mistakes/errors thus far, but this one just escapes me.

Here's the code, I marked where the compiler states the error:

```
#import "Sprite.h"

@implementation Sprite

@synthesize x, y, speed, angle, width, height, scale, frame, box, rotation, wrap,render;
@synthesize r, g, b, alpha, offScreen;

- (id) init
{
self = [super init];
if (self) {
    wrap = NO;
    x = y = 0.0;
    width = height = 1.0;
    scale = 1.0;
    speed = 0.0;
    angle = 0.0;
    rotation = 0;
    cosTheta = 1.0;
    sinTheta = 0.0;
    r = 1.0;
    g = 1.0;
    b = 1.0;
    alpha = 1.0;
    offScreen = NO;
    box = CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0);
    frame = 0;
    render = YES;
}

return self;
}

- (void) draw: (CGContextRef) context
{
CGContextSaveGState(context);

// Position the sprite
CGAffineTransform t = CGAffineTransformIdentity;        
t = CGAffineTransformTranslate(t,x,y);                  
t = CGAffineTransformRotate(t, rotation);
t = CGAffineTransformScale(t, scale, scale);
CGContextConcatCTM(context, t);

// Draw our body
[self drawBody: context];

CGContextRestoreGState(context);
}

- (void) setRotation: (CGFloat) degrees
{
rotation = degrees * 3.141592/180.0;
}

- (CGFloat) rotation:
{                                     **THIS IS WHERE THE LINE ERROR OCCURS**
return rotation * 180.0/3.141592;
}
```

any help is appreicated. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Remove ':' from that line

```
- (CGFloat) rotation:
```

':' indicates that you are passing some parameters to that function.

**IMPORTANT**: It seems you are using "rotation" name for method and variable. Please change that.

Comment: thank you! so strange that the book would make a ridiculous typo like that. I should've caught that

Comment: @John There is no problem in using the same name for an ivar and a method.

Answer (score 1):

```
- (CGFloat) rotation: **ERROR IS IN THIS LINE**
```

solution- Either pass parameters or remove colon (:)

Answer (score 0):

Take out the colon and try like this

```
- (CGFloat) rotation
{                                     **THIS IS WHERE THE LINE ERROR OCCURS**
return rotation * 180.0/3.141592;
}
```